# Calling a helper function and passing in data to chart.js

Tags: reactjs, express, chart.js

I created a helper function to work around my [chart.js](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/getting-started/usage.html).

First, on my index.html file I put the ff:

```
   <div id="app"></div>
   <canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
```

Next, to call chart.js, I created a helper function with the necessary data/arguments on it:

```
export const chartUI = (labels, data) =>{
  var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");

  var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
        labels: labels,
        datasets: [{
            label: 'RATES',
            data: data,
            backgroundColor: [
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
            ],
            borderColor: [
                'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
            ],
            borderWidth: 1
        }]
    },
    options: {
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero:true
                }
            }]
        }
    }
});

};
```

Now on my component where I need to put my data on I called the function so it can manipulate and display the data:

```
import React from 'react';
const helper = require('../../../helpers/utils')

const Chart = (props) => {
  return(
    <div>
       {props.info.map(item => {
          return <p>{helper.chartUI(item.time, item.rates)}</p>
       }) }
    </div>
  )
};

export default Chart;
```

When I run this code i did not see any chart on the frontend and also I got this error: `Uncaught TypeError: this.ticks.map is not a function The above error occurred in the <Chart> component: TypeError: this.ticks.map is not a function`

PS. Here's the the type data I am flowing from my app:

```
{
    "rates": [
            {
                "time": "2018-04-13T15:45:19.5968204Z",
                "asset_id_quote": "$$$",
                "rate": 4000000
            },
            {
                "time": "2018-04-13T15:45:41.7725202Z",
                "asset_id_quote": "1ST",
                "rate": 37714.501225721289835941919668
            }
}
```

Comment: I guess `labels` arguments require `array` and you are passing it `item.time`. Try to converting it to array and see if it fixes the problem.

Comment: @FarhanTahir: I already converted it.

Comment: I don't think you are converting `item.time` to array its timestamp.

Comment: `helper.chartUI(item.time, item.rates)}` item.time here not array